# What is the difference between module and project in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I use Eclipse for Java, but I have seen a lot of people that use IntelliJ. I use PyCharm and it was really good for Python, and since IntelliJ is also made by JetBrains, I am giving it a try. However, I don't know the difference between module and project. Also, I am a beginner.

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35637559/differences-between-intellij-project-and-module

Answer (score 2):

You can regard the project in intellij as the workspace in eclipse, regard the module in intellij as the project in eclipse.

Comment: so, i can have multiple module inside of a projects?